# How do I start a lazyRow in the last index on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

How can I make the lazyRow go to the last index when I launch my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun MessageList(messages: List<Message>) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    // Remember a CoroutineScope to be able to launch
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LazyColumn(state = listState) {
        // ...
    }

    ScrollToTopButton(
        onClick = {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                // Animate scroll to the first item
                listState.animateScrollToItem(index = lastIndex)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Please refer the docs for more [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#control-scroll-position)

You can do the same thing for LazyRow

Comment: It works all right but is there a way to do it without having to click a button? Just launch the app and it automatically go to last index

Comment: coroutineScope.launch {
                // Animate scroll to the first item
                listState.animateScrollToItem(index = lastIndex)
            }

move this in your lazyRow

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [**`animateScrollToItem`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState#animatescrolltoitem):

Something like:

```
val itemsList = //... your list
val listState = rememberLazyListState()

// Remember a CoroutineScope to be able to launch
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

LazyColumn(state = listState) {

    items(itemsList){
        Text( "Item $it" )
    }
}
```

To launch automatically you can use:

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        listState.animateScrollToItem(index = itemsList.size-1)
    }
    onDispose { }
}
```